# How to define two export handlers within one function and use variable from one handler in another one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am quite new to Node JS Lamda functions and still learning.

I have a function and here is the TEST working code:

```js
const https = require("https")
var url = "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html"

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var variable_1 = "test 1"
  var variable_2 = "test 2"

  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda!") + url,
  }

  return response
}
```

I need to perform two actions within the same function. Is it possible to have two export handlers like this? and how can I use variable from one handlers in another?

```
const https = require("https")
var url = "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html"

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var variable_1 = "test 1"
  var variable_2 = "test 2"

  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda!") + url,
  }

  return response
}

//second handler - is this possible?

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var variable_3 = variable_1 + variable_2

  // TODO implement
  const response2 = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body:
      JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda - 2nd function!") + url + variable_3,
  }

  return response2
}
```

Comment: your question can be interpreted  in different ways. so what are you exactly trying to do ? invoke both functions at the same time ? or have them exported so you can choose which one to call ?

Answer (score 0):

What you do instead is create multiple export functions as follows;

```
// First Function
exports.doSomethingA= async function() {
return something;
};


// Second Function
   exports.doSomethingB= async function() {
   return something;
};
```

Imagine those two function were in a file called customer.js - you can them import that file in another file and invoke the function as follows;

```
const customer = require('./customer');

exports.doSomethingC= async function() {
  await customer.doSomethingA();
  await customer.doSomethingB();
}
```

In your case, I would have a seperate file with the two functions.  Then invoke those functions in your handler as above. Don't forget to import.

Answer (score 0):

You can *lift* `variable1` and `variable2` to higher scope:

```js
const https = require("https")
var url = "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html"
var variable_1 = "test 1" // moved to higher scope
var variable_2 = "test 2" // moved to higher scope

exports.handler1 = async (event) => {
  // if you want to update variable1 and variable2 (optional)
  // optional : if these  variables need to change everytime handler1 is called; you can change them here.
  variable1 = 'foo'
  variable2 = 'bar'
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda!") + url,
  }

  return response
}

//second handler - is this possible?

exports.handler2 = async (event) => {
  var variable_3 = variable_1 + variable_2

  // TODO implement
  const response2 = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body:
      JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda - 2nd function!") + url + variable_3,
  }

  return response2
}
```

Good Luck...